# OnShowFileChooser of BridgeWebChromeCLient not getting called?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-webview

I have created an ionic project and converted to android via 'ionic cap buil android' command. This app just needs to open the gallery on a button click .
I see the code to open gallery in BridgeWebChromeClient.java as 'onShowFileChooser' method. But I am seeing that whatever changes I make here , its not getting reflected in the Android app. It is not even printing the log which is given as the first line. I think this method is not getting triggered. Moreover I am unable to actually locate , where the button click is actually taking place.

```
@Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(
        WebView webView,
        final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
        final FileChooserParams fileChooserParams
    ) {


      Logger.debug("Starting BridgeWebChromeClient onShowFileChooser");
        List<String> acceptTypes = Arrays.asList(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes());
        boolean captureEnabled = fileChooserParams.isCaptureEnabled();
        boolean capturePhoto = captureEnabled && acceptTypes.contains("image/*");
        final boolean captureVideo = captureEnabled && acceptTypes.contains("video/*");
        if ((capturePhoto || captureVideo)) {
            if (isMediaCaptureSupported()) {
                showMediaCaptureOrFilePicker(filePathCallback, fileChooserParams, captureVideo);
            } else {
                permissionListener =
                    isGranted -> {
                        if (isGranted) {
                            showMediaCaptureOrFilePicker(filePathCallback, fileChooserParams, captureVideo);
                        } else {
                            Logger.warn(Logger.tags("FileChooser"), "Camera permission not granted");
                            filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                        }
                    };
                final String[] camPermission = { Manifest.permission.CAMERA };
                permissionLauncher.launch(camPermission);
            }
        } else {
            showFilePicker(filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Is there anything to be done , to work in that file ??
Please help .